# Creating a space efficient generic object in java

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm trying to create an object that is simultaneously as space efficient as possible but can also work generically and I'm running into a major problem. One of the optimizations I wanted to make is to remove the wrappers from the keys (of which there can be an arbitrary number of arbitrary types). But I am running into an issue with the nature of generics in Java.

It seems that to make a function generic it MUST take in Objects which would require wrapper classes. A workaround would be if I could dynamically create a primitive typed array. Does anyone have an idea how I could accomplish this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: +1, sounds like a XY problem

Comment: So long story short, I'm making space optimizations to a key/map data structure. Right now I am trying to build the key holder. There can be any number of key fields and any number of keys (which is why I couldn't just, say, store 10 empty int arrays and use them as needed)

Comment: To optimise you have to make assumptions and take out work/data based on those assumptions.  Without being able to make assumptions you can't optimise it further, which is why you get in a design spiral.

Comment: MAybe your terminology doesn't match mine, but isn't `new int[i]` a "dynamically created primitive typed array"? If not, what would you call that, then?

Comment: Hmm... So I guess I have to see what assumptions I can make... This is pretty horrifying from a design perspective but what if I were to create a separate class for each of the primitive types? Within the int array class itself I can always assume that input will be an int, and can thereby optimize accordingly. Since I only need to know whether the key matches from the outside I can input the key, the intarray will type check internally, and just return a Boolean for whether there is a match (removing the need to correctly return the type of a value in an ovject array)

Comment: When I say dynamically created I mean I don't know how many keys there are beforehand. An array list would work if space weren't an issue, but these arrays need to be malleable in size

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would doubt that your intention will make any measurable improvement in storage, but to answer the question...

I assume your question may be summarized as "If passed wrapper objects, how do I store them as an array of primitives?", and implies that `null` objects are not allowed.

You can dynamically create a primitive array using library methods from the JDK. You haven't shown any code, so modify this as you need:

Here's a simple approach:

```
public static int[] unwrap(Integer... integers) {
    int[] array = new int[integers.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
        array[i] = integers[i]; // auto-unboxing
    }
    return array;
}
```

where you would probably just overload constructors or factory methods for the different wrapper types.

Here's a more general example of how to create a primitive array dynamically:

```
public static int[] unwrap(Integer... integers) {
    int[] array = (int[]) Array.newInstance(int.class, integers.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
        array[i] = integers[i].intValue();
    }
    return array;
}
```

You can adapt this pattern for your other wrapper classes, for example by storing in a map which wrapper class uses which primitive class (eg `Integer.class --> int.class` here), but the problem gets stickier when it comes to getting the right value from the wrapper, for example knowing to call `Integer.intValue()` for an `int` and `Long.longValue()` for a `long`.

However, you can mostly solve this reflectively:

```
private static Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> map = new HashMap<Class<?>, Class<?>>() {{
    put(Integer.class, int.class);
    put(Long.class, long.class);
    put(Float.class, float.class);
    put(Double.class, double.class);
    put(Character.class, char.class);
    put(Short.class, short.class);
    put(Byte.class, byte.class);
    put(Boolean.class, boolean.class);
}};

public static <T> Object unwrap(T first, T... rest) throws Exception {
    Class<?> outputType = map.get(first.getClass());
    if (outputType == null) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    Object array = Array.newInstance(outputType, rest.length + 1);
    Method getter = first.getClass().getMethod(outputType.getSimpleName() + "Value");
    for (int i = 0; i < rest.length + 1; i++) {
        T target = i == 0 ? first : rest[i - 1];
        Array.set(array, i, getter.invoke(target));
    }
    return array;
}
```

The remaining problem is that a primitive array is *not* an instance of `Object[]`, so you can't declare the return type as an a array (there is no common type for primitive arrays).

Nevertheless, you have your array object that you can save and interrogate later to rewrap into wrappers using a similar approach, except you would invoke the constructor of the wrapper class and pass it an element from the array, accessed via `Array.get(array, i)`.